# Excel - Need to find if anything from column A is found within column B

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Basicaly, I have 2 lists of email addresses in Excell...

```
Column A = Holds over 2051 rows of email addresses
Column B = Holds about 1994 rows of email addresses
```

I need a way to find out which email addresses in Column A aren't found in Column B, and preferably output the results in, either a new sheet, or in Column C.

Than after that I need to be able to find which email addresses in Column B aren't found in Column A (if any) and output that list into, either a new sheet or Column D.

How can I do this?

Comment: Pivot Table. or 3rd column and if condition with Vlookup

Comment: now we're cookin with gas!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In either a new sheet or column C use a combination of VLOOKUP() and IFERROR() and drag that formula for every line of A.

`=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, $B$1:$B$1995, 1, 0)), A1 & " NOT FOUND IN COLUMN B", "FOUND IN B")`

This will return two different messages depending on if the e-mail was found or not in B.

Comment: Error `Excel cannot calculate a formula`.

Comment: Ok, never, no error here, but this doesn't work, it only gives me the A1 - B1 comparison result.  Don't know how to drag the formula for the entire C Column.  I selected the enture C Column, and pasted in the formula, but it doesn't work.  Only gives me results for the first row

Comment: I corrected my formula. It had a small typo that caused incorrect behavior.

Comment: Also, if you want the reverse lookup as well then you would need to use another type of formula because you cannot use VLOOKUP from right to left.

Comment: Ok, I think this is working now, but how do you drag it down for the whole column?  I don't understand how to do this?  Doesn't seem to drag...  What exactly do I drag?

Comment: How don't understand your question. I tested it and it works fine when I drag it. Have you perhaps forgotten the locks ? (dollar signs)

Comment: I'm confused on how to drag it exactly?  Sorry, I'm just not very familiar with Excel...

Comment: Click in the cell containing the formula. In the lower right corner click and drag the black square.

Comment: I don't see a black square...

Comment: At this point what you need is a tutorial on Excel. I don't want to be mean but that is the case.

Comment: Also, I have used your formula on rows that are definitely not in Column B for sure, but it still says:  FOUND IN B.

Comment: I fixed it. My edit was wrong earlier.

Comment: Ok, I found out how to get it within the whole column, all you have to do is select the entire column, and Hold down the CMD (in MAC) key or CTRL (in Windows) key when you hit enter after pasting in the formula and it does it for all columns.  BUT AGAIN - You're formula does not work, it is saying "FOUND IN B" for all rows in column C and that's NOT POSSIBLE!

Comment: Ok, so i have switched the columns from B to A, and A to B, and now it tells me that something isn't found (and it is right), but it ONLY WORKS on the FIRST ROW now!  Will now work in any other rows.  Maybe it is because you have `A1` in your formula??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32344/discussion-between-alexandre-p-levasseur-and-solomon-closson)

Answer (score 1):

Why not copy paste the data from column B onto the end of column A?  Then set the conditional formatting for the column to highlight all items whose count exceeds one.  Use this formula, "`=countif($A$1:A1,A1)>1`", without the quotes.  Make sure the whole column is selected when doing this.

Another method for maintaining the separation of data.  In column C use a formula like this `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,$B$1:$B$100,1,0)),A1,"")`; change the ranges to match your data ranges.  Then fill down the formula until the end of data in column A.  To fill down, select the desired range and press 'Cntl+D'.  Repeat this for column D but swap the A and B references in the formula and fill down until the bottom of the column B data.  This will result in data in columns C & D that list the unique values.  Copy and paste these values, be sure to paste as values if the default paste is used Excel will paste the formulas and not the data, into another set of columns (E & F) or the same columns, then sort each column to eliminate the spaces.

Comment: Well, ok, this sounds great.  However, now I am thinking, is there a way to find out if Column B is not found in Column A, and vice versa?

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, I need to compare both and output the email addresses into, either 2 separate sheets, 1 sheet with 2 columns, or Columns C and D (which are empty).

Comment: Using your approach I get the following error:  `Excel cannot calculate a formula - Call references in the formula refer to the formulas result, creating a circular reference... etc. etc.`

Comment: Can you show an example of this?  Be sure that this was entered into the conditional formatting box.

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?  Be sure to check that the 'Analysis ToolPak' add-in is active.  You can find this in Excel 2010 by going to File -> Options -> Add-Ins.

Comment: Excel for Mac 2011, Version 14.3.2, am adding it into the box next to where Fx is defined at the top.

Comment: I do not have the Analysis ToolPak add-in available to me.  The only add-in in there is:  `Solver.Xlam`

Comment: Please try this to get the toolpak: [MS Excel Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914208)

Comment: Conditional Formatting
• [MS Help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/mac-excel-help/highlight-patterns-and-trends-with-conditional-formatting-HA102927734.aspx)
• [youtube vid](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IXVkYC4a4h4)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Sub ..

```
Sub CrossCheck()
Dim LastA, LastB, r As Range
Dim x, Cn, Dn As Long

Set LastA = Range("A65536").End(xlUp)
Set LastB = Range("B65536").End(xlUp)
Cn = 1
Dn = 1

For x = 1 To LastB.Row
    Set r = Columns("B").Find(Cells(x, 1), , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If r Is Nothing Then
      Cells(Cn, 3) = Cells(x, 1)
      Cn = Cn + 1
    End If
Next
For x = 1 To LastA.Row
    Set r = Columns("A").Find(Cells(x, 2), , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If r Is Nothing Then
      Cells(Dn, 4) = Cells(x, 2)
      Dn = Dn + 1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Hope this help !!

Comment: What is this?  A Macro??  How do you use this code?

Comment: @SolomonClosson .. VBA Code .. Assign the code to your button or whatever .. I already tried it in Excel 2007 ..